# Converting a unicode format string into actual utf string

Tags: python, utf-8

When I call an api, I get an output like this-
`\\u092f\\u0939 \\u0909\\u0926\\u093e\\u0939\\u0930\\u0923 \\u092a\\u093e\\u0920`

The utf encoding is stored as a string. So string[1] here would be 'u'.
Anyone know how do I convert this into actual utf-8 string using python?

Comment: Show us how you retrieve the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `codecs` module:

```
>>> s = "\\u092f\\u0939 \\u0909\\u0926\\u093e\\u0939\\u0930\\u0923 \\u092a\\u093e\\u0920"
>>> print(s)
\u092f\u0939 \u0909\u0926\u093e\u0939\u0930\u0923 \u092a\u093e\u0920
```

So:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(s, 'unicode-escape')
'यह उदाहरण पाठ'
```